# CSS Class with !important is not being applied?

Tags: css

I have this HTML:

```css
.text-success {
    width: 75px;
    padding: 1px;
    color: #4c9709;
}

.SomethingOrOther {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 37px !important;
    color: #FFA500 !important;    
}

.lineheight {
    line-height: 21px !important;
}
```

```html
<b><span id="lblSomethingOrOther" class="text-success lineheight SomethingOrOther"><a onclick="SomeAction('Something', 'Other');"><u>Text which appears incorrectly</u></a></span></b>
```

In the `text-success` class, we apply a few things but one of them is `color: #4c9709;` (green). The `SomethingOrOther` class also applies `color: #FFA500 !important;` (orange) but when I run the software, the text is the wrong color; it's using `text-success`'s green.

Why is it not respecting the `!important` flag and using the second color? Tried IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

I can *probably* remove the `text-success` class from the HTML but this is behaving correctly on our Live server but not our local test server and I'm trying to figure out why...

Comment: Could you please share your css?

Comment: I am seeing Orange color https://jsfiddle.net/6xjj4kr4/

Comment: try adding more specifity - `b span.SomethingOrOther` (if the class is unique to the page and not global)

Comment: its because you are not specifying the correct container.. "SomethingOrOther" does not equal "a" in this context. ie you are changing the color of the text in SomethingOrOther and not "SomethingOrOther a u"...

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Is `b span` a typo or is that "legitimate" CSS? I'm not super versed as a web designer; sorry.

Comment: @sab669 I added code snippet and also link to jsfiddle above I see Orange colour which is right behavior

Comment: @devil_coder I'm not sure why your JS fiddle works. I tried creating one myself and observe the correct behavior there, too. But yet on my actual project....

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I changed the CSS to be `span.SomethingOrOther` and that fixed the issue, so if you'd like to post that as an Answer I will Accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @sab669 ok sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to lie with the specificity value. The more specific you are with css, the higher up in the hierarchy it comes. E.g.

a class is less specific then an id, so the id wins any overrides
inline styles are more specific than an id, so styles win.

the !important rule may be in place, but not working due to the specificity of the css. Adding the element type before the class should make the specificity win over other rules (other than inline !important)

example css:

```
.class {color: #fff;}
#id {color: #000;} /*id will win*/

span.class {color: #fff;}
#id {color: #000;} /*id will lose because span.class narrows down selectors moreso than #id*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes , it works.you can see it [here](https://jsbin.com/gasoqipoba/edit?html,css,output).

```
<span id="lblSomethingOrOther" class=" lineheight SomethingOrOther"> 
<span >this is blue.</span>
<a onclick="SomeAction('Something', 'Other');"><u class="text-success">this is green.</u>
</a>
</span>
```

Css :

```
.SomethingOrOther {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 37px !important;
    color: blue !important;    
}
.text-success {
    width: 75px;
    padding: 1px;
    color: green ;
}
.lineheight {
    line-height: 21px !important;
}
```

You have to use !important css attr on parent and other css attr on childes or parent's nodes.

Comment: Your example is the opposite of the behavior I'm observing on my site. The color with `!important` is not being applied, for some reason.